# Finding the format of my timestamp in Python

Tags: python, datetime

My time format is screwy, but it seemed workable, as a string with the following format:

```
'47:37:00'
```

I tried to set a variable where:

```
DT = '%H:%M:%S'
```

So I could find the difference between two times, but it's given me the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '47:37:00' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'
```

Is it possible there are more elements to my time stamps than I thought? Or that it's formatted in minutes/seconds/milliseconds? I can't seem to find documentation that would help me determine my time format so I could set DT and do arithmetic on it.

Comment: Because 47 is not a valid hour?

Comment: Looks more like Minutes, Seconds, Microseconds?

Comment: It is possible that 47 represents 1 day + 23 hours (24 + 23), but that depends entirely on how it is encoded. Perhaps you can tell based on your use case.

Comment: Yes, 47 did represent a day and 23 hours. Thanks for your notes.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you set 47 to %H, that is not a proper value. 
Here is an example:

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016/07/28 12:37:00','%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

print dt
```

Output: 2016-07-28 12:37:00

Comment: Thanks for this. That was indeed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote "I can't seem to find documentation that would help me determine my time format so I could set DT and do arithmetic on it"

Try this:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Way down to the bottom.

And yes, when the %H is matched with 47, you get boom the error.

Comment: Clearly I wasn't looking hard enough. Thanks! Appreciate it.